# Extract function name from a function

Tags: c#, reflection, f#

How can I create a function called getFuncName that takes a function of type (unit -> 'a) and returns its name.

I was talking to one of the C# devs and they said you could use the .Method property on a Func type as shown in an **example** [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gmWmVF).

I tried to convert this to F# :

for example convert (unit -> 'a) to a type Func<_> then call the property on it but it always returns the string "Invoke".

```
let getFuncName f =
    let fFunc = System.Func<_>(fun _ -> f())
    fFunc.Method.Name

let customFunc() = 1.0

// Returns "Invoke" but I want it to return "customFunc"
getFuncName customFunc
```

A bit of background to this problem is:

I have created an array of functions of type (unit -> Deedle.Frame). I now want to cycle through those functions invoking them and saving them to csv with the csv name having the same name as the function. Some hypothetical code is below:

```
let generators : (unit -> Frame<int, string>) array = ...

generators
|> Array.iter (fun generator -> generator().SaveCsv(sprintf "%s\%s.csv" __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ (getFuncName generator)))
```

This is being used in a scripting sense rather than as application code.

Comment: AFAIK you will not have an easy time getting this but maybe someday we will get [nameOf](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/13) ;)

Comment: Just seems strange that this can easily be done in C# but not F#

Comment: Just in case this is an XY problem, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: well F# is not the *better* language in all cases

Comment: Why not have an array of tuples, each holding a function and its name?

Comment: @MarkPattison Yeah thanks this is what I have done in the end. Having a getFuncName would have just saved me from having to copy and paste all the function names as strings though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you searched for information, but the first query to the search engine gave me this response:

```
let getFuncName f =
   let type' = f.GetType()
   let method' = type'.GetMethods() |> Array.find (fun m -> m.Name="Invoke")

   let il = method'.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()
   let methodCodes = [byte OpCodes.Call.Value;byte OpCodes.Callvirt.Value]

   let position = il |> Array.findIndex(fun x -> methodCodes |> List.exists ((=)x))
   let metadataToken = BitConverter.ToInt32(il, position+1) 

   let actualMethod = type'.Module.ResolveMethod metadataToken
   actualMethod.Name
```

> Unfortunately, this code only works when F# compiler does not inline function body into calling method.

Taken from [here](http://ntrush.blogspot.com.tr/2014/06/f-sharp-getting-function-name.html)

Although there may be a more simple way.

Comment: Yes this works but please take careful note of the comment under the code snippet mentioning it doesn't work where the function has been inlined